# Okta access token validation in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, okta, okta-api

Currently, the Spring boot microservices use Spring Security OAuth2 for authentication and authorization.
The services are in AWS API Gateway.

Now, we want to migrate to Okta SSO.
What would be the suitable approach to implement access token validation (locally and remotely) for client facing services ?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated (apart from the option of using **API Gateway Lambda authorizers**).

The existing OAuth2 implementation should be in place along with new implementation for Okta token validation until the migration is complete.

Thank you.

Comment: why using API Gateway Lambda authorizers does not work?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be anyhow different, except that you'd need to change authorization server endpoint to be an Okta one. Or maybe I'm not fully understanding the scope of planned changes on your side.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention about the versioning part. The existing OAuth2 implementation should be in place along with  new implementation for Okta token validation until the migration is complete.

Comment: I'm not sure if spring boot can support validation of tokens for 2 authorization servers. But if you don't mind to do it manually, it should not be difficult to achieve.

Comment: I have been looking into Spring Cloud API gateway which will intercept incoming requests, validate the access token with Okta, then forward the request to downstream microservice. Does this seem like a good approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Datawiza provides a solution for that if you are OK with using a 3rd-party commercial solution.

https://docs.datawiza.com/best-practice/aws-api.html